# How do I get at least one solution as a single variable so that I can assign it to other equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$x-y+z=4\\ 2x-y=6\\ x+y-3z=0$$

Sole the following linear equation system using elementary row operations. Once you arrive at a solution to a single variable, you may assign it to other equations. The solution must be written a row vector, and note how many solutions are available.

Steps I took:

$${ R }_{ 1 }={ 2R }_{ 1 }-{ R }_{ 2 }$$

Which equals to: $$0x-y+2z=2\\ 2x-y=6\\ x+y-3z=0$$

Then, $${ R }_{ 3 }={ R }_{ 3 }+{ R }_{ 1 }$$

Which equals to: $$0x-y+2z=2\\ 2x-y=6\\ x-0y-z=2$$

I think this is as far as I can go without getting things like $x=z+2$ and etc. I don't understand how I can possibly conduct row operations for a single variable here. Where do I go from here? Guide me in the right direction, please.

Comment: $R_1=R_1-R_2$ eliminates $y$ follow this  by $R_3 = R_1+ 2R_3$ to get $x$

Comment: I ended up with $y=2x-6$ and $z=x-2$. What does that tell me about the amount of solutions?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer what about the third equation ?. I think you should do  $R_3 = R_3 - R_1$ , $R_2 = R_2 - 2R_1$ so you get rid of the first number in the second and third row. Then you do $R_3 = R_3 - 2R_2$ leaving you with $x-y+z = 4, y-2z = -2$ hence $x-z = 2$ you will have infinitely many solutions

Answer (score 1):

$$\left( \begin{array}   {rrr|r}       
\\
1 & -1& 1&4\\
2 & -1 & 0&6 \\
1 & 1 &-3 &0       \end{array}     \right)
\to \left( \begin{array}   {rrr|r}      
\\
2 & -2& 2&8\\
2 & -1 & 0&6 \\
2 & 2 &-6 &0     \end{array}     \right)
$$
$$ \to \left( \begin{array}   {rrr|r}      
\\
2 & -2& 2&8\\
0 & 1 & -2&  -2  \\
0 & 4 &-8 &-8     \end{array}     \right)
$$
$$ \to \left( \begin{array}   {rrr|r}      
\\
1 & -1& 1&4\\
0 & 1 & -2&  -2  \\
0 & 0 &0 &0     \end{array}     \right)
$$
so we have a one parameter family of solutions ( a line instead of a point)

Let $z=t$

then $y-2t=-2 \implies y=2t-2$

 and $x- (2t-2)+t=4 \implies x=t-6$

So the solution is every point on the line

$$\ell(t) = (1,2,1)t+(-6,-2,0)$$

Comment: I'm not supposed to use gauss elimination to arrive at my solution. In addition, I'm not quite sure of what you did towards the end with the substitution.